# What's wrong with this strpos and ternary operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator, strpos

```
strpos($mydata,'Εntity') === false) ? 'normal' : 'other'
```

It returns always 'normal' even if

```
 $mydata="Entity: This data must work."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I though your string has a weird encoding if you take a look into a hex editor and compare the `Entity` from your string and from the strpos call you will see the difference:

```
//string
45 6e 74 69 74 79  
//strpos call
ce 95 6e 74 69 74 79
```

So to solve this now, just don't copy it from here on SO just write it normal with your keyboard and all should work fine. The proof here: http://3v4l.org/lbL4v